# Excel - finding partial text in a cell/range, return that text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find partial text from specific `cells/range` and return that value in other cell.

```
Column A                 Column B
TP-K19-00041-SPC-A4-0    SPC
TP-K19-00042-DAS-A4-0    DAS
TP-K19-00043-WTD-A4-0    WTD
```

From above, partial text from `Column A` (example "SPC") is identified and copied in `Column B`. Currently, this is done manually, I wanted to know if there's a way to use any formula to automate this.

Comment: if all your data in column `A` has the same format (as in example above), you could use this formula `=MID(A1,14,3)`

Answer (score 1):

Sure - check out the [MID function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/Text-Functions/ss/2011-01-31-excel-2010-truncate-text-strings-mid-function.htm).

In your example, if you type the formula

```
=MID(A1,14,3)
```

You should get the desired output.